# [Permission denied: '/Users' on amazon instance during file upload with django and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, ubuntu, file-upload, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

when trying to upload files on my ubuntu amazon instance running django 1.4 through mod_wsgi I get an error

```
Exception Value:  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py in makedirs, line 157
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

I hope someone can explain what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the bug i had a wrong path in my django settings file